# How to create on line loading progress bar in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-progressbar

I want to implement this progress bar in my app. What it is called and how this style of progress bar can be achieved?
Any help will be appreciated
Required Output:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
   />
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can check some Good Libraries for it.
I think This library can help you

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/370

or more here

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/76?sort=rating

Thanks